# How work 'for' in Pine language (TradingView) and how call MACD in loop?

Tags: pine-script

Please teach me how to use the for loop in the Pine language (scripts for TradingView charts).
I made a test indicator (code below), which displays the MACD.
In green chart, I simply display MACD at the top level of the script.
I get the same MACD value in red chart, but taken inside the 'for' loop. See how it works:

- the loop increments the value of n from 0 to 20
- when n is 0, the script takes the MACD value and writes it to the cell val
- then there are another 20 empty steps.
- at the end, the script displays val on the screen, completing the red chart

Logically, the green and red graphics should ideally match, since they display the same values. But they are different !!!
Help understand the error. Thank you.

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")

[_,_,currMacd] = macd(close[0], 12, 26, 9)
plot(currMacd, style=plot.style_histogram, color=color.green)

//
float val = 0.0
for int n = 0 to 20
    [_,_,tempMacd] = macd(close[n], 12, 26, 9)
    if n == 0
        val := tempMacd

plot(val, style=plot.style_histogram, color=color.red)
```

[image: Screenshot of TradingView]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not too sure what you're trying to accomplish here, but your MACD is already calculated on past bars, so you only need to refer to past values:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")

[_,_,currMacd] = macd(close, 12, 26, 9)
plot(currMacd, style=plot.style_histogram, color=color.orange, linewidth = 8, transp = 60)

float val = 0.0
for int n = 0 to 20
    val := currMacd[n]
    if n == 0
        break

plot(val, style=plot.style_histogram, color=color.red)
```

Comment: Hi Luc, I think he's trying to play around with the `for` loop for learning purposes. So achieving identical results would prove his understanding on how to use the `for` loop

Comment: ) Hi Glauco. Thx for answering qs btw. Helps a lot. Can't use built-ins like that in `for` loops, with the idea they will recalculate on each loop iteration. They need to run on every bar, for the same reasons explained [here](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#why-do-some-functions-and-built-ins-evaluate-incorrectly-in-if-or-ternary--blocks).

Comment: Hello, 

Thank you for your reply. 
I read the link in last comment. Perhaps, pine-script (version 4) doesn't support to call the function macd() in for loop.

P.S.
I update your example, and I take bar with number 20 in my script. The mistake still exist:
`//@version=4
study("My Script")

[_,_,currMacd] = macd(close[20], 12, 26, 9)
plot(currMacd, style=plot.style_histogram, color=color.orange, linewidth = 8, transp = 60)

float val = 0.0
for int n = 0 to 20
    val := currMacd[n]

plot(val, style=plot.style_histogram, color=color.red)`

Comment: I updated my answer with a chart showing the code in the answer works. It's useless to include code snippets in comments. Note that I just included your `for` loop in the example to show that you can't hope to re-evaluate MACD in the loop. It won't work, but you can refer to past values of MACD using the syntax I showed. In any case, the fundamental question is: What are you trying to accomplish? What's the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: "you can't hope to re-evaluate MACD in the loop" - ok, it is an answer. "What's the problem you are trying to solve?" - I wanted to call external functions in loop 'for', like in classic language, but it is forbidden.  Thank you.